# unable to receive response from ajax post request using slim framework 3

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, slim

### Edit:

The problem has been corrected. The localhost address for the ajax request should have been 127.0.0.1 and not **121.0.0.1**

---

on my client I have the following code to request a POST on localhost/login

```
<html>
<title> Welcome </title>
<script>
function makeRequestObject(){
   var xmlhttp=false;
   try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
   } catch (e) {
      try {
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      } catch (E) {
         xmlhttp = false;
      }
   }
   if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   return xmlhttp;
}

function showdata()
{
   var xmlhttp=makeRequestObject();
   var user=document.getElementById('user_name').value;
   var pass=document.getElementById('password').value;
   var url = 'https://121.0.0.1/login';  // invalid ip address for localhost
   var params = 'uname='+user+'&'+'pass='+pass;

   xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
         if( content ){
            document.getElementById('userdiv').innerHTML = content;
         }
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.send(params);
}
</script>
<body>
Enter user name : <input type="text" id="user_name" /><br/>
Enter your password : <input type="text" id="password"/><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="showdata()" value="Submit"><br/><br/>
<div id="userdiv">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have on my server side the following slim handler function :

```
$app->post('/login', function () use ($app){
        $req = $app->request();
        $uname = $req->params('uname');
        $pass = $req->params('pass');
        $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode($uname);
        exit;
});
```

My problem is that the ajax call is made to the server as a request is seen on the server. But no response is coming back from the server.

here is are screen shots of what is happening in chrome developer tool

http://s29.postimg.org/5379a7rt3/image.png

I can see that the initial call to localhost is working
but the next ajax call to login is not working since only request is produced but no response is received. Response subsequently times out

Comment: please replace the **"content-type"** string with **"Content-type"**

Comment: Tried it. Thats not the problem

Comment: did you remember to call **$app = new Slim();** at the beginning of the code and **$app->run();** at the end of it?

Comment: Actually my code is well structured. There is one index.php file that requires this postRoutes.php file and getRoutes.php file. The main index.php file has the new slim instance and app->run methods. But this file postRoutes.php just has the code that is displayed along with <?php on top and ?> at the bottom

Comment: if it helps, $app->get('/', function(){}); in the getRoutes.php works. So I know its not a problem with the routing.

Comment: Hi please forgive me for wasting your time. I can't forgive myself anyway. The problem is that localhost is 127.0.0.1 not 121.0.0.1.... I corrected the problem and it works now

Comment: lol :) i looked at it and didn't realized that its 121 instead of 127.. please update your question for other users. thanks

Answer (score -1):

i think your request should be in GET method not in post for above case.Try to change to do this request in GET instead of post.